# How to execute stored procedure on first day of a new year in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I want to execute the following stored procedure on the first day of new year.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE archive_reservation_data
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ARCHIVED_RESERVATION
        SELECT 
            r_id, START_DATE, END_DATE, C_ID,V_ID, TOTAL_COST, 
            'Name' AS ADDED_BY, GETDATE() AS ADDED_DATE 
        FROM 
            RESERVATION

    TRUNCATE TABLE RESERVATION
END
```

Comment: then create a job and schedule it for the first day of january, every 12 months

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create a SQL Agent Job to execute your stored procedure and schedule it for the 1st January.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190268(v=sql.120).aspx

Answer (score 0):

SQL Agent is the standard way to do this.

If you can't use SQL Agent for any reason (Express Edition, for example), write a .BAT script to execute the sproc using SQLCMD, and schedule that using the task scheduler.